# How to detect if "developer settings" are enabled on the device?

Tags: android

I want to detect if "developer settings" are enabled on the device.

I found nothing to solve this problem ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
int devOptions = Settings.Secure.getInt(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS_ENABLED , 0);
```

if developer options are enabled the value will be 1, otherwise it will be 0